# DecisionTreeClassifier TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

While using Jupyter notebook I never had this problem with the `fit()` function.
But with this code I do:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

data = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
test_data = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

X = data.drop(columns=['Survived'])
y = data['Survived']

model = DecisionTreeClassifier
model.fit(X, y)
prediction = model.predict(test_data)
prediction
```

The train.csv and test.csv files were successfully read by pandas (I visualized X and Y in Jupyter).

The output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_23200\3416706318.py in <module>
      9 
     10 model = DecisionTreeClassifier
---> 11 model.fit(X, y)
     12 prediction = model.predict(test_data)
     13 prediction

TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

How do I fix this bug?

The data used:
https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/titanic/data?select=train.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Fix for the error (syntax error):

First of all the error you have encountered can be fixed by adding parenthesis  when calling the model to use `model = DecisionTreeClassifier()`

After adding the parenthesis in the model the code again will encounter an error since your `X` data have multiple columns with string value.When training a model the algorithm (DecisionTreeClassifier) will only accept numerical values for X and y. Please see this [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Either your dataset do not have the column 'Survived' at that level or data.drop() does an in-place removal, or possibly a 3rd spooky alternative.
Either way this behaviour is caused by supplying a None argument to a function which is not prepared for that, python just disregards it as not being supplied at all.